# Ubuntu 7.10 problem

Tags: nvidia

Hi I wanna ask I've just install Ubuntu 7.10 and when I write sud apt-get upgrade I get massage said could not get lock /var/lip/dpkg/lock . I know you stop supporting 7.10 is that mean is not gonna be updated too . Thanks a lot

Comment: why do you install a os which is 8 years old?

Comment: My computer didnt accept Ubuntu new version that is what ...

Comment: What is the model of the computer you have?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to type `sudo apt-get upgrade`, so you forgot to type the 'o' in the command.
Second of all Ubuntu 7.04 is over 8 years old, so I wouldn't recommend to use that. It does not receive any upgrades anymore so trying the command described above makes no sense anymore.
From your question I understand that you think that Ubuntu is made by the people of AskUbuntu. This is not true. AskUbuntu is part of a group of knowledge exchange sites or Question and Answer sites to state it differently. Ubuntu is supported by Canonical which is a different company.
Most computers that are not too ancient can run Ubuntu so I advise you to try Ubuntu 14.04 or higher. If your computer can't run this please let us know about any errormessages or anything else which enables us to investigate what's wrong.